# Retrieve numbers after comma (from double numbers)

Tags: java, double

Imagine that I have 4,81 (double), how can i get the figures after the comma?

I want to receive 8 as a Integer and 1 as another.

Thanks

Comment: one way is to convert to string and manipulate that, extracting individual characters, then converting them back to int

Comment: What is the input, a String or a double?

Comment: Exactly what @Adam said. A double is always represented as a number with a floating **point**, not a comma. So do you have a `double` with value `4.81` or a `String` containing `4,81`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doubles are tricky to work with when you're interested in decimal properties such as the decimal digits of the fractional part.

I suggest you let `String.valueOf` do the transformation to decimal digits and work with the resulting string.

```
double d = 4.81;
String s = String.valueOf(d);

for (int i = s.indexOf(".") + 1; i < s.length(); i++) {
    int digit = Character.getNumericValue(s.charAt(i));
    System.out.println(digit);
}
```

**Output:**

```
8
1
```

Comment: But the numbers are still not converted to integers, and that's what the OP asked. Perhaps you should add the conversion to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make this kind of loop:

```
double number = 4,81;
while (condition) {
  number *= 10;
  int nextNumber = Math.floor(number) % 10;
}
```

Comment: but a double number cannot accept a comma `,` I am not sure how the asker is having a comma in a double

Comment: I think, that coma/dot is determined by regional settings.

Comment: I guess he meant your code. You used a comma as the separator and this is invalid.